# how to Insert multiple items into calculated column from single line of text

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

My single line text value is `Colombia|d12fd403-83ac-4982-bc2c-3efdeb86e1f1; EP|1ac55076-7d65-4846-af18-67658fdf276a;Bronswerk|a5e873d7-61b6-454c-98cd-8c30ec17604f`. I want to get the output in calculated column as `Colombia;Ep;Bronswerk`.

The single line text is getting values from multi selected managed meta data column. According to that we have to split values in calculated column.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

did you think of using ms flow expression?, well i tried a very simple and basic flow in order to split the input you have mentioned above,

I created a random list which contain 4 columns (Title, Colombia, Ep, Bronswerk)
the Title column will be our input, the rest will be filled using the flow i will show you below

[image: splitting flow]

1-when an item is created (is a trigger which will run our flow when a new input enter to our list)
2-Compose (i used a simple formula which is composed of some MS flow expression)
here is it :

```
array(split(triggerBody()?['Title'],';'))
```

it consist of getting the title, spliting it into an array (where the split character is the **;** like you see) the output will be a simple array:

`[
     "Colombia|d12fd403-83ac-4982-bc2c-3efdeb86e1f1",
     "EP|1ac55076-7d65-4846-af18-67658fdf276a",
     "Bronswerk|a5e873d7-61b6-454c-98cd-8c30ec17604f"
    ]`

3-Update the item (now we need to update the item, i mean the rest of the columns by each element of the previous array respectively.

```
concat(outputs('Compose')[i],'') #i from 0 to 2
```

and that is it ! here is a simple test:
i enter a new input
[image: new input] 
a new item is created
[image: new item is created]
and suprise :p
[image: result]

I hope this will help you,
Best regards.